# Oracle: using result from CONCAT() in like clause()

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use a concat result in one of my queries in oracle:

```
Select * 
  from T1 
       join T2 
       on T1.f1 like CONCAT(T2.f2,'%')
```

This is not producing results for `T2.f2` rows with `NULL` value. I assumed that would have resulted in something like `T1.f1` like `'%'`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not completely sure of what you're attempting;
however, to get around the specific issue you have, try [COALESCE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM T1 
       JOIN T2 
       ON T1.f1 LIKE CONCAT( COALESCE( T2.f2, '' ), '%' );
```

Comment: Thanks, seems the original issue was not with NULLs (I saw empty values in the f2 columns). The rogue T2.f2 rows had only spaces in them. So the T1.f1 values were not matching with them. I used a TRIM(T2.f2), much like coalesce here. As newbie I do not have reputation to vote up, but my sincere thanks for the helping hand.

Comment: In Oracle `''` and `NULL` are the same thing. So `COALESCE( T2.f2, '' )` is exactly the same as `T2.f2`

Comment: Should be `coalesce(concat(T2.f2, '%'), '%')` or `coalesce(T2.f2||'%', '%')` to get a `'%'` in the face of null values for T2.f2.

Answer (score -1):

Below query may help you

```
SELECT * 
  FROM PINKY1 
       INNER JOIN PINKY2 ON NOTES LIKE VAL1 
 WHERE NOTES LIKE VAL2 
   AND NOTES LIKE VAL3 
   AND NOTES LIKE VAL4 
   AND NOTES LIKE VAL5
```